# How do native apps handle a large number of nodes in the view?

Tags: android, html, ios, performance, dom

I am a web developer and one of the current issues is the migration towards single page applications (SPA) and the challenges this brings about. For example, if we implement the infinite scroll, we can easily find ourselves with hundreds of document object model (DOM) nodes rendered in the browser.

Subsequently, if we need to make some changes that will propagate through all of them, this can take a huge bite off our performance. That is partially a reason why libraries like React gained popularity - virtual DOM.

Virtual DOM creates a virtual representation of the whole DOM tree and whenever any changes are made, it compares the old and new state, and updates only those nodes that have changed. Ionic, a hybrid app framework, has its own solution for infinite scroll that hides those nodes that are not in the view to speed up the performance.

So I was wondering, how do native apps cope with a large number of nodes in the view? Any social app with a feed can reach that number after a few seconds of scrolling. Is it handled by the OS? Is it an issue at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue if you don't adhere to some best practices. Like loading variable images asynchronously or keeping the layout as flat as possible. For list views its the [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) technique.

The List implementations on Android usually don't instantiate as many views as there is content in the provided dataset but only as many (and some extra) as could fit on the screen. When a view goes off screen the ListView caches that instance and provides it back to you when a new entry from the dataset should be shown. You then simply put the values from the model in the provided view (or better in the associated ViewHolder) and its done.

Other issues might arise if the dataset is changed frequently or is simply to huge. If an entry in the dataset changes, then you probably don't want to redraw the whole ListView but only the view that changed. Older List implementations cannot handle this. If something changes, every visible view in the list is redrawn. Modern List implementations like the RecyclerView don't have this limitation. Not only does it enforce the ViewHolder technique it also provides methods to tell the RecyclerView what item changed so it can pull of some efficient redraw magic.

If the dataset is to large, then the best way to avoid memory or performance limitations is to only load the latest items from the dataset and ask the user to load more. Or paging.

So yeah, the framework does help you is most cases. But there is enough room to mess things up.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a similar technique for iOS apps?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have very much iOS experience right now. At least for UICollectionView they seem the  use a similar caching strategy. Each time the View requests a cell for a particular row (cellforIndexAtPath) you can and should use the  'dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier' method to obtain an instance of a cell instead of creating new one all the time. But as I said I'm missing  experience to return a qualified answer.